# Should I ask my current company to reimburse me expenses surrounding a flight cancellation?

Tags: software-industry, contracting, travel, expenses

I am a software engineer working as a contractor. In the contract with my current place, they have agreed to pay for my travel.

Coming home from my first business trip to their office, my flight was cancelled due to weather and I was forced to get a hotel room and fly out the next morning. Should I ask the company to reimburse me for the hotel room?

Comment: Sorry, voting to close, specific to the company you are contracting for.  Also location specific, in the UK for example you'd be able to claim travel costs against tax, so impossible to give a general answer.

Comment: What do you mean "should I ask?" It's not our business to tell you what to do. Having said that, they are the only party that might have an interest in reimbursing you and that could possibly reimburse you. And of course, the rules for reimbursement are company-specific.

Comment: Keep open. Company policy is pretty standard, and an answer can reflect that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  A company reimburses you for a trip not a flight or hotel.  There are things that can happen on a trip that will cause more money to be spent.  As long as you are following the company guidelines they should reimburse you for something as basic as a cancelled flight and accommodations.  I have never heard of a company not reimbursing this, so if this were the case I would look at building this "talk" into future trips or find another job.

Comment: But the airline should pay for the room as its their delay

Comment: @Pepone - In the US if it is because of weather the airline has never paid for my hotel.  If they had a mechanical issue yes but not because of weather or things they can't control.  Not sure the laws in other countries.

Comment: @Pepone It depends on where you are.  Here in the US I wouldn't expect to see a penny from the airline for a weather event unless I was a very elite traveler.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - I usually try to give airlines some pity case about not be able to pay for a hotel and say that I will have to end up sleeping at airport.  The response I get the most is, we have blankets we can let you borrow.   Sometimes they call a hotel to hook me up with a good rate (usually half normal).

Comment: @blankip I thought there where international agreements for delay compensation - and I thought Ryanair treated passengers badly

Comment: @Pepone International agreements (if there are any) wouldn't apply to domestic US flights.  And the reason US airlines don't pay for the room is because its not their delay, its considered an act of god (as they can't control the weather any more than you can).